# How to prevent Artifactory repo URL from authenticating a second time?

Tags: artifactory

We have Pipelines that simulate a functional test using artifactory, however one of the steps require to gather artifacts from an Artifactory URL, the steps hangs as Artifactory is asking for a login screen to authenticate the user, how can we overcome this?
is there are another way to access artifacts without the URL?

Artifactory asking for authentications with a login screen during pipeline runs.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you query Artifactory. The login screen I expect only from UI, while if you follow an automated process you absolutely have to use REST API or JFrog CLI.
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/introduction-to-the-artifactory-rest-apis (Authentication chapter) ; https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/authentication?tocId=CCpb8PYC~OtyV267~LgOOg

Comment: Hi there thanks for your kind reply....we will investigate the suggested methods. The developers are using the python method to run their unit testing so I've also suggested they explore https://pypi.org/project/artifactory/ package as part of it.